# Understanding "Boss the stone" and other phrases

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, british-english, slang, understanding

The Passage is from Jerusalem by Jez Butterworth. Ginger is a DJ and he never had the chance to work as a DJ and he is high at the moment. According to these lines, what's these phrases means: "public awaits", "I’m roasted", "Boss the stone" and "boss it"

DAVEY. They’ve disbanded. 2 Trevs is no more. They’ve
gone home. You want to get up The Cooper’s car park. Your
public awaits.

GINGER. But… I’m… I’m… I’m… I’m… I’m… I’m…
I’m… I’m… I’m… I’m…

DAVEY. It’s your big break, mate.

GINGER. I’m roasted.

DAVEY. Use it, mate. Boss the stone, mate. Get up on top and
boss it. Your canvas is The Cooper’s car park, your brush
Beyoncé and ‘The Birdie Song’. It is time to bring the
ruckus.

Comment: Could you [edit] your post to include more details? What's the context? Also, it's better to ask one question per post and show your research. See M-W: intr. v. 1 for [awaits](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/await). Also see [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for more tips and examples.

Comment: @Em.♦ I added some more details about the passage and these issues are related together so I have to ask them in one question.

Comment: @Em.♦ I got it. Thanks. about "awaits" I'm not sure, I presume that the "public awaits" is "waiting room".

Comment: _Your public awaits_ means _your audience is waiting for you_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**boss the stone**

Ginger is [stoned](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stoned)

"to boss"  means  [to be in control of something](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/boss)

Boss the stone  = Control your drug-befuddled mind.

**public awaits**

The people who have come to see your performance as a DJ are waiting for you.

**I’m roasted**

GINGER. I’m roasted.

DAVEY. Use it, mate.

This means "Use the fact you are roasted (under the influence of drugs) to your advantage. Being stoned will not hold you back."

Note: "roasted" is not a usual synonym for "stoned" but the context seems to make it so.